# Accessing images with CSS url() in Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

This is from the Primefaces docs:

> Button Icons
>
> An icon on a button is displayed using
>   CSS and image attribute.

```
<p:commandButton value=”With Icon” image=”disk”/>

<p:commandButton image=”disk”/>
```

> .disk is a simple css class with a
>   background property:
>
> .disk {
>       background-image: **url(‘disk.png’)** !important; }

My question is: where does this url() point to? In other words, where should I put my images so that the CSS could access it?

I've tried /resources, /resources/img, no luck. Yes, it was working with an absolute URL (one that includes the context path), but that makes the application not portable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your question is more concerned with the client-side aspects of things, so even though I don't know Primefaces, here's a stab at answering it:

CSS paths are relative to the location of where the CSS rule is declared.

If this is in your HTML (in a <style> block), then disk.png has to be in the same directory as your file.

If this rule is in a separate CSS file, then disk.png should be in the directory where the CSS file is.

If you create a directory images, then the directory will be relative from the CSS too.

Hope this helps?

Answer (score 11):

Simple solution:

IF you are using JavaServer Faces 2.0 you have chance to put all resources inside specially designed directory. So you need to have this folder structure in web app:

```
-rootdir
--resources
---images
----disk.png
```

And to receive image in css background you should type something like this:

```
.disk {
background: url(#{resource['images/disk.png']}) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem for a moment and I reckon documentation about it is unclear!
It works this way for Primefaces commandButton and similar (menuItem, submenu, etc):

What I did is:

- Download a theme from the theme library in PrimeFaces website (example: aristo or redmond).
- Unzip the archive to your web application **resources** folder, (in my case: **root/resources/css/aristo**
- Notice that in aristo folder you have : **theme.css** and /images folder where an indexed png image contains all the icons used by the theme.
- If you open the theme.css you'll notice that to access an indexed image icon you should call two classes : **.ui-icon** and **.ui-icon-theiconyouwant** (the .ui-icon retrieves the index png using `#{resource['primefaces.......png']}` and .ui-icon-agivenicon delimit the icon by its X & Y position (index) in the png image).
- Now output the theme.css into you application, by using `**<h:outputStyleSheet />**.` Best way to do it is between  tags of your template.
- So in your xhtml or jsp, do `**<p:commandButton image="ui-icon ui-icon-someicon"} />**.`
- Now if you want to add your personal images to use with a `<p:commandButton`, create classes in theme.css :

  .smiley {
      background-image: url("#{resource['images/smiley.png']}") !important; /*this will be ignored by Internet Explorer if not compatible*/
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      }

  Normally JSF accesses the first images folder available within your resources folder.
- Now do: `<p:commandButton image="smiley" value="Smile" />`